# How to close metro application programmly from other process?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

What I need is to kill launched Metro application in Windows 8 programmly.

Would it be just a simple process, I would write

```
Process.GetProcessById(processId).Kill()
```

or

```
var applicationProcess = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
applicationProcess.CloseMainWindow();
applicationProcess.Close();
```

but these do not work in my case.

I've tried also this WinApi function for terminating processes

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool TerminateProcess(IntPtr hProcess, uint uExitCode);
```

It actually terminates the process, and I can see that the process does not exist in Task Manager any longer, but still I can see the application half-alive (IE on the picture):

[image: still alive IE]

So, I'm running out of ideas. Any help?

UPDATED:

Probably my processes list would be of any help. Here it is before I've killed anything:

audiodg : 3200
cmd : 4588
conhost : 5820
csrss : 2144
csrss : 416
csrss : 480
DeploymentManagerService : 1756
dwm : 796
dwm : 2852
explorer : 1592
Idle : 0
iexplore : 5696
iexplore : 5644
LogonUI : 2140
lsass : 572
rdpclip : 3540
Receiver : 1668
rundll32 : 1432
SACMonitor : 3344
SACSrv : 1888
SearchIndexer : 2312
Sender : 968
services : 564
smss : 312
spoolsv : 1340
sqlwriter : 1000
svchost : 1416
svchost : 780
svchost : 328
svchost : 856
svchost : 676
svchost : 2576
svchost : 2712
svchost : 1376
svchost : 832
svchost : 1004
svchost : 632
svchost : 1608
System : 4
taskhost : 6036
taskhost : 3040
taskhostex : 1440
VSSVC : 2732
wininit : 464
winlogon : 524
winlogon : 2416
WmiPrvSE : 168
WUDFHost : 1096

Comment: IE (desktop/metro) uses several processes, make sure you killed all of them

Comment: Thank you for the answer and please have a look to my reply to Michael.

Answer (score 0):

@magicandre1981 is quite correct IE will run multiple processes so closing one via its pid will not close the entire application just a instance with in it

for example

[image: image of taskmanger]

as you can see chrome is running on pid 17816 , 3140 .........

meaning closing one will not close chrome

to close all processes to something like a web browser try the following

```
        var proccessCollection = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");

        foreach (var proccess in proccessCollection)
        {
            proccess.Kill();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But it does not seem to be my case for at least two reasons: 1) I have the same problem with any metro application (I've tested microsof in-build such as music, video, finance and so on)  and 2) even if I kill all the processes marked with ie name, it is still alive.
Processes lists I've added to the main question